# CLicking on the camera button in the android emulator

Tags: android, camera, emulation

The camera button on the android emulator is disabled.
I can't click on it and when I hover with the mouse the background is not blue like in the other buttons.
I've tried to add "camera support - true" hardware but the button is still un-clickable.

How can I click on the button?
What should happen when clicking on the button? I don't have an real android device so I might be able to click on the button without knowing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try launching the camera from the menu.  Still you won't be able to use it as a camera, it will just launch a bouncing box over a checkered pattern.  If you want to test the camera you will need an actual device.

Although I have heard of someone having some instructions that will enable the emulator to use a webcam, I haven't tried this though, so I'm not sure if it works.

Comment: I'm more interested in the camera button itself.
Is there a way to make it clickable?
I want to have a broadcast receiver listening to the camera button click event.